# ctypes pure python vs ctypes django

Tags: python, django, dll, ctypes

A strange problem I think:

I have a C library that reverses a char*. When I use ctypes in pure python I get the proper solution. However when I try the same code in a django view I get a wrong answer.

Pure Python:

```
import sys
from ctypes import *
path = "library.so"
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
reverse = lib.reverse
reverse.restype = c_char_p
```

when I use "reverse('pepe')" I get 'epep'

With django, with the same code I get only 'p'.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you give us some more information about what "With django" means? Maybe what context within django you are using "reverse"?

Comment: With django implies using this code in a django view.

Comment: Django uses unicode. Basically it places a NULL byte after every char in a string. It might be the case that library.so doesn't see the string right.

Comment: I know there is a django function called 'reverse' that is supposed to reverse a URL, could your code accidently be calling that instead of your ctypes `reverse`?

Comment: @PaulWoolcock Calling to "lib.reverse()" gets the same error. Thanks for your idea. It was a great one :)

Comment: @IonutHulub I'm newbie with that kind of problems. Any Idea how to test your hypothesis?

Comment: @PabloFlores Did you write the `library.so` yourself? If so, try printing the string from inside the library before reversing it. If all you get is "p" then that is your problem, and you need to change the library to implement unicode support (the naive solution is to read only bytes on even positions because the bytes on odd position in the string will always be NULL)

Comment: To test the hypothesis even easier run this in 'pure' python: `lib.reverse(unicode('pepe'))`. If it prints "p", you have identified the problem...

Comment: @IonutHulub you find the problem. THANKS A LOT!!!!(with the first post, I cant vote you positive... :_()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aswer to my questions is on comments. Thanks a lot to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664657/ionut-hulub for the answer.